# Error installing mod_apns

Tags: ejabberd-module

I am trying to add mod_apns to ejabberd (15.10) server
I've got the module from this [link](https://github.com/mrDoctorWho/ejabberd_mod_apns),

These are the steps I followed:

1. I copied mod_apns.erl file to ejabberd/bin folder

2.From ejabberd module installer I compiled the file :

```
./erlc -I ejabberd/include mod_apns.erl
```

3. It produced some warnings:

```
mod_apns.erl:26: Warning: function hexstr_to_bin/1 is unused
mod_apns.erl:28: Warning: function hexstr_to_bin/2 is unused
mod_apns.erl:127: Warning: variable 'From' is unused
mod_apns.erl:127: Warning: variable 'To' is unused
mod_apns.erl:127: Warning: variable 'Type' is unused
mod_apns.erl:157: Warning: variable 'Opts' is unused
mod_apns.erl:164: Warning: variable 'Host' is unused
```

4. I ignored the warnings(?!) and copied .beam file to ejabberd/lib/ejabberd/ebin folder
5. I copied my cert.pem and key.pem files to ejabberd/conf folder (?!)
6. I configured ejabberd.yml file as follows:

code:

```
mod_apns:
  address: "gateway.push.apple.com"
  port: 2195
  certfile: "cert.pem"
  keyfile: "key.pem"
```

I even tried:

```
mod_apns: {}
```

7. start ejabberd

But the ejabberd won't start and the error file shows this error:
Problem starting the module mod_apns for host..

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these lines of code to mod_apns.erl and it solved the problem of starting module:

```
-ifndef(LAGER).
-define(LAGER, 1).
-endif.
```

right after:

```
-export([start/2, stop/1, message/3, iq/3]).
```

I created .beam file and restart ejabberd server. the module is installed and ejabberd server started however, still I don't get any notifications. It should be another question though.